# How to do multiple t.test() at once

Tags: r, t-test

I got two datasets.

Each dataset got lots of columns of the same species, sampled at two different occasions.

Now I want to see if the mean value of the species is significantly different of each other. I learned that I have to do a paired t-test for this.

I figured out the formula to do this is:

```
 t.test(dataset1$'specie',dataset2$'specie')
```

Q1: Am I using the correct function for a paired t-test?

Q2: Given that I've actually done it correctly. How do I interpret the [answer?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwtsU.png). What does the t=  tell me? The p-value is low, does that mean the mean values of the species are similar or not?

Q3: Is there a way to make R automatically compare all the same species from the two datasets against each other, or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: Subset each species and do a t-test in this subset. You can employ a for loop or a sort of apply family functions.

Answer (score 0):

1. t.test(dataset1$'specie', dataset2$'specie', paired=TRUE)
   Without it, it is the Welch's t test which does not sound like what you are looking for.
2. Simply put, high T mean that it is highly unlikely the two population means are similar.
   Low p values mean that they are not similar. It depends on your cutoff point but 1.096e-10 is incredibly low. If you were looking for a cutoff at 0.05, then anything above that is considered not significant.

   See the following link for more details:
   https://www.r-bloggers.com/paired-students-t-test/
3. You can make it a function or object or something.